# Why must I convert an integer to a float64 to type match?

Tags: go

I have been playing around with Go and I ran into a (non?)feature of Go while running the following code:

```
a := 1     //int
b := 1.0   //float64

c := a/b   //should be float64
```

When I ran this I get the following run-time error:

```
invalid operation: a / b (mismatched types int and float64)
```

I thought GoLang was supposed to be pretty good with type inference.  Why should it be necessary for me to write:

```
c := float64(a)/b    //float64
```

In general, given two number types, c should be inferred to be the smallest type that contains both.  I can't see this as being an oversight, so I am just trying to figure out why this behavior was decided upon.  For readability reasons only?  Or would my suggested behavior cause some kind of logical inconsistency in language or something?

Comment: Also see [The Go Blog: Constants](https://blog.golang.org/constants). In your specific example making `a` an untyped constant (i.e. `const i = 1`) would avoid the need for explicit conversion.

Comment: @DaveC Yeah, I read that last night.  It was a good read and cleared up a few details for me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is mentioned in the FAQ: [Why does Go not provide implicit numeric conversions?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#conversions)

> The convenience of automatic conversion between numeric types in C is outweighed by the confusion it causes. When is an expression unsigned? How big is the value? Does it overflow? Is the result portable, independent of the machine on which it executes?
>   It also complicates the compiler.

That is why you need:

- either to do an explicit **[type conversion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)**:

  ```
  c := float64(a)/b
  ```
- or to use `var float64`

  ```
  var a, b float64
  a = 1     //float64
  b = 1.0   //float64
  c := a/b
  ```

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't think that automatically converting numeric types would break the strictly-statically typed language as is shown in C.  I didn't consider the complications involved with unsigned vs signed and overflow problems.

Comment: @breeden yes, you can see what one of the creators of that language Go (Rob Pike) has to say about this: http://blog.golang.org/constants: "When designing Go, we decided to avoid this minefield by mandating that there is no mixing of numeric types. If you want to add i and u, you must be explicit about what you want the result to be."

Comment: Thanks you for this post. The creators of Golang omitted several features from the C language for being overly complex. In the long run, I've come to appreciate these omissions despite not liking it at first.